# read CSV file into a List of strings and then loop to identify an item

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm just learning Windows Forms with C# and I'm having a lot of trouble rewriting my Console app into a window forms app. Here is my code in the Console App:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"C:\Users\annage\Desktop\SCHOOL\POS409\data.txt"; //path for CSV file        

        List<List<string>> EmployeesInfo = new List<List<string>>();
        string inputLine = "";
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
        int whileLoopRan = 0;

        while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)     //enters items into array                                                             
        {
            if (whileLoopRan == 0)
            {
                whileLoopRan++;
                continue;
            }
            whileLoopRan = 1;
            List<string> inputArray = inputLine.Split(new char[] { ',' }).ToList();//remove extra spaces
            inputArray = inputArray.Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList();
            EmployeesInfo.Add(inputArray);
        }

        List<EmployeeTaxes> EmployeeList = new List<EmployeeTaxes>();

        foreach (List<string> EmployeeInfo in EmployeesInfo)
        {
            String employeeType;
            employeeType = EmployeeInfo[5];
            EmployeeTaxes employeeTaxType = new EmployeeTaxes();
            employeeTaxType.GrossPay = double.Parse(EmployeeInfo[3]);

            if (employeeType == ("W2"))
            {
                double taxes;
                taxes = .07;
                employeeTaxType.taxes = double.Parse(EmployeeInfo[3]) * .07;
                employeeTaxType.totaltaxes = employeeTaxType.taxes * 12;
            }  
            else if (employeeType == ("1099"))
            {
            }
            EmployeeList.Add(employeeTaxType);
        }
        DisplayData(EmployeeList, EmployeesInfo);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }



    private void DisplayData(List<EmployeeTaxes> employeeList, List<List<string>> employeesInfo)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < employeeList.Count; i++)
        {
            List<string> Row = employeesInfo[i];
            string fullName = Row[0];
            string address = Row[1];
            string employeeType = Row[5];
            string developerType = Row[6];

            EmployeeTaxes taxRow = employeeList[i];
            double grossPay = taxRow.GrossPay;
            double taxes = taxRow.taxes;
            double totalGrossPay = taxRow.TotalGrossPay();
            double annualTaxes = taxRow.totaltaxes;
            double netPay = taxRow.Netpay();

            Console.WriteLine("Welcome, !", fullName); // shows greeting and users name
            Console.WriteLine("Address: ", address);  //shows address entered
            Console.WriteLine("Gross Pay: $", grossPay);  // Shows gross pay entered
            Console.WriteLine("Employee Type: ", employeeType);
            Console.WriteLine("Monthly taxes are 7%");  ("Monthly Taxes Paid are: $" + taxes.ToString("N2"));  // calculated the taxes paid monthly

            Console.WriteLine("Annual Gross Pay: $" + totalGrossPay.ToString("N2"));    // calulates gross pay * 12months

            Console.WriteLine("Annual Taxes Paid: $" + annualTaxes.ToString("N2"));     // calulates taxes * 12months

            Console.WriteLine("NetPay: $" + netPay.ToString("N2"));
            Console.WriteLine("Developer Type: ", developerType);
        }
    }
}
```

I am reading from a CSV .txt file and then I add it to a list of strings and I search for the "employee type" and then based on that value I loop it to do a calculation and then print out all the values.

I was able to read the csv file into a textbox in windows form, but I cannot figure out how to loop it and read the specific value and then continue with my calculation. 
here is what I have for my console windows form:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.listBox3.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple;
    ReadingCSVFile();
}

public void ReadingCSVFile()
{
    List<List<string>> EmployeesInfo = new List<List<string>>();
    string inputLine = "";

     using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\annage\Desktop\SCHOOL\POS409\data.txt"))
     {
         string line;
         while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
             listBox3.Items.Add(line);
         List<string> inputArray = inputLine.Split(new char[] { ',' }).ToList();
         inputArray = inputArray.Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList();
         EmployeesInfo.Add(inputArray);
     }
}

private void DisplayData(List<EmployeeTaxes> employeeList, List<List<string>> EmployeesInfo)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < employeeList.Count; i++)
    {
         List<string> Row = EmployeesInfo[i];
         string fullName = Row[0];
         string address = Row[1];
         string employeeType = Row[5];
         string developerType = Row[6];

         EmployeeTaxes taxRow = employeeList[i];
         double grossPay = taxRow.GrossPay;
         double taxes = taxRow.taxes;
         double totalGrossPay = taxRow.TotalGrossPay();
         double annualTaxes = taxRow.totaltaxes;
         double netPay = taxRow.Netpay();
    }
}
```

Where can I add my loop? I tried using as much of my code in both formats, but I know console.writeline needs to be changed for windows form, but I haven't gotten that far yet. 
Any assistance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You are also having trouble making your first post :) that formatting is disgusting

Comment: To start with Just like `EmployeeTaxes` you should create a class to represent EmployeeInfo and store the employee related information read from file to the class object and add that object to a list of EmployeeInfo

Comment: yep, please format your code. It is to hard to read.

Comment: I think you should use a csv parser, like http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is easier to use Lambda Expressions.
So your code would look like this:

```
        public void Test()
        {
            List<string> myList = new List<string>();
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"2018-03-16.csv"))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = reader.ReadLine();

                    var values = line.Split(';');

                    foreach (string item in values)
                    {
                        myList.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            this.FindItem(myList);
        }

        private void FindItem(List<string> myList)
        {
            // if you want the value
            var match = myList.FirstOrDefault(stringToCheck => stringToCheck.Equals("your item to check"));

            // if you just want to check if it exists
            var match2 = myList.Any(stringToCheck => stringToCheck.Equals("your item to check"));
        }
```